# How to replace first overflown element with ellipsis "..."

Tags: jquery, overflow, ellipsis, css

I have a div with mutiple `<p>` tags inside it, the div is fixed width and height and I want to replace just the text that overflows the parent with "..."

```
<div class="container" style="width:200px; height:400px; overflow:hidden;">
   <p class="pText">one one one one one one one one one one one one </p>
   <p class="pText" >two two two two two two two two two two two two </p>
   <p class="pText">three three three three three three three three </p>
   <p class="pText">four four four four four four four four four four </p>
   <p class="pText">five five five five five five five five five five </p>
   <p class="pText">six six six six six six six six six six six six six </p>
</div>
```

at some point the text overflows the parent, at which point i want to replace the overflow word with "...".

like so:

```
___________________________
| one one one one one one |
| two two two two two two |
| two two                 |
| three three three three |
| three three three       |
| four four four four four|
| four                    |
| five five five five ... |
|_________________________|
```

**thing is the text wraps horizontally just fine.
it gets clipped vertically once its too long which is fine.
what i need is to completley remove the line that is semi-visible and replace the last word before it with "..."**

i guess its impossible by CSS so i dont mind trying with jQuery.

thanks alot for your help!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-overflow

Comment: You need only last line to be clipped?

Comment: yes only the last word even. the first word that overflows.

Comment: Antony text-overflow wouldnt work in this situation, since the text it self never overflows the <p> element it is in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution I often use:

[Multiline Ellipsis in pure CSS](http://www.mobify.com/dev/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css/)

There is also a jQuery plugin: [dotdotodt](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/)