# How to hide the word that is overflow text in HTML?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using creating web site using codeigniter. In my view page i have display user input data in user profile view but problem is when the paragraph is too long it will display like this
[image]

you can see that there is a more information button is can't find because of the paragraph so i need to make it like this 
[image]

now it is more clear and look nice how can i do this ?I try using text-overflow but it only work in horizontal.need quick help.

this the php code in view page..

```
 <div id="top-slider">
            <div id="layer1">            
                <?php if (!empty($package_data)){?>


                        <?php if (!empty($package_data['Photos'])){ ?>
                            <img src="<?php echo base_url()."files/media/".md5($profileID)."/host_package/".$package_data['Photos'][0]['Title'];?>">
                            <h2>- <?php echo $package_data['PackageTitle']; ?> -</h2>
                            <p>"<?php echo $package_data['Description']; ?>"</p>
                        <?php } else{?>    
                            <img src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets_profile/img/bg/2.jpg">  
                            <p >"<?php echo $profile_info['PersonalDescription']; ?>"</p>
                        <?php }?>
                <?php }else{ ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets_profile/img/bg/2.jpg">

                        <p>"<?php echo $profile_info['PersonalDescription']; ?>"</p>       
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
</div>
```

after HTML page render this is view page source looks like

```
<div id="top-slider">
            <div id="layer1">            
                            <h2>- Nepal By Drive -</h2>

                            <p>"Nepal is first mentioned in the late
                             Vedic text, Atharvaveda Parisista as a place exporting blankets, and in
                             the post-Vedic Atharva Siras Upanisad.[22] In Samudragupta's Allahabad 
                            inscription it is mentioned as a bordering country. The 'Skanda Purana' 
                            has a separate chapter known as 'Nepal Mahatmya', which "explains in 
                            more details about the beauty and power of Nepal." Nepal is also 
                            mentioned in Hindu texts such as the Narayana Puja.[2"</p>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show your CSS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to replace first overflown element with ellipsis "..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15729527/how-to-replace-first-overflown-element-with-ellipsis)

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/croq6oc0s84ebn3/styles.css

Comment: You should edit your question and add your CSS code (relevant part only), so that it will be more helpful for upcoming visitors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a fixed width and height (might need to use percentage for this to look right on your site) and then use overflow and text overflow like this:

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

in your css.